# How to make google sheets remember value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make somethin like a Chutes & Ladders game in excel. Meaning that i automatically generate a number from 1-6 like a dice roll and then i want to make a system, which will sum all of these rolls (all are saved in individual cells) and determine where should the player be standing on cells 1-100.
I made a cell which sums all of the rolls and then a SWITCH function, which moves the result number if it detects a number that is either a chute or a ladder and outputs the resulting number.
The problem is that lets say that player lands on cell "2", there a ladder there and leads to cell "21". If the switch detects 2, it correctly says 21. But then the player rolls the dice, lets say 4 and it outputs 6, because its just 2+4=6 and doesnt remember the previous 21. The correct answer should be 27. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: If you're working with Google Sheets you can use REDUCE or SCAN, depending on your layout. It will not "save" the variable but will keep the process of calculation and application of SWITCH. If you bring more details we'll be able to help you better

Comment: I have a row for each player that consists of 90 cells for dice rolls. I then sum all of them and this result I put in SWITCH which is just simple  =SWITCH(B3,14,4,28,10,...,B3) in which B3 is the cell witch sum and all the numbers are just rules for chutes and ladders (if 14, then go to 4....)

Answer (score 0):

Create a public variable to hold the previous "location".

```
Public accumulator
```

Then

```
accumulator=accumulator+diceroll1+diceroll2
```

Comment: How do I make a public accumulator in excel? Im trying lambda functions but cant really figure it out